# password isn't hashed on custom user model using rest api

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

I was trying to create a custom user model and create a rest-api but when I send post request it creates a user model but the password isn't hashed I am using set password in my user_create method and it works fine for comand line based superuser but when I use other user created by the api it don't I am using set password method but it don't work either
**Here is my usermodel**

```
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """custom user model"""
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # django required and django user field declaration
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    objects = UserProfileManager()
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email
```

**my profile manager**

```
class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
    """User manager for our custom user model"""

    def create_user(self, name, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User Must have an email')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(name=name, email=email)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, name, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            name=name,
            email=email,
            password=password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
```

**my serializer**

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializes our custom django user model UwU (nice serializer desu ka)"""


    class Meta:
        model = models.UserProfile
        fields = ('id','name','email','password')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password':{
                'write_only':True,
                'style':{
                    'input_type':'password'
                }
                }
            }
        def create(self, validated_data):
                """ Create and return a new user"""
                user = models.UserProfile.objects.create_user(
                    email=validated_data['email'],
                    name=validated_data['name']
                )
                user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
                user.save()
                return user
```

**my viewset**

```
class ProfileViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """View set for user profile"""
    serializer_class = serializer.UserProfileSerializer
    queryset = models.UserProfile.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
```

I am new in django rest-framework so please help me

Comment: use set_password() to save password (in create()) otherwise it will save password as simple text. that's the error.

Comment: Check if in your settings you have declared `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.UserProfile'`

Comment: @JacekBBudzynski I have done it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do `set_password` explicitly in seiralizer as you already 
have a `create_user` [**`manager method`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/). So try like this:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   class Meta:
        model = models.UserProfile
        fields = ('id','name','email','password')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password':{
                'write_only':True,
                'style':{
                    'input_type':'password'
                }
             }
         }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = models.UserProfile.objects.create_user(
                    email=validated_data['email'],
                    name=validated_data['name'],
                    password = validated_data['password']
               )
        return user
```

Comment: I did so but still nothing

Comment: @FaizUlHassan can you please fix the indentation like the updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem
my '''create_user''' takes 3 args like following

```
create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields)
```

so when I called it in my `register()` view, I did it as follows:

```
from .models import CustomUserModel

register(request):
   # assuming you are using model form
   form = RegistraionForm()
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = RegistraionForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         # fetch your fields 
         email = form.cleaned_data['email']
         password = form.cleaned_data['password']
         # fetch other fields as well
         user = CustomUserModel.objects.create_user(
            email = email,
            password = password,
            other_field = other_fetched_field`enter code here`
         )
         # no need to use set password here
         return redirect('path')
```